Unconventional flatbread recipe/process, concern about food safety RESULTED IN: Speedy's Flatbread recipe (see answer: Adjusted Recipe)
After reading several flat bread recipes, I came up with the following.  As mentioned, I'm concerned about proper cooking.  Depending on the thickness of bread it can leave the oven and when I tear the layers apart, it's a bit sticky still.  Is it done enough?

1 cup WW Flour
[edit, forgot this] 1 egg
1 cup shredded Kale
1/2 tsp baking powder
1/2 tsp salt
1 tsp olive oil
Filtered water to near water consistency
[edit]optional: 1/2 cup sweet corn (no topping necessary w/ this!)



flat skillet on medium heat until solid, about 1 min
cooling rack until I have 4
oven at 350 F for 20 minutes


Crank the oven to 425 or so, put a silpat or parchment on a baking sheet, and skip the skillet. Try it some day...

If it’s “near water consistency” this would be a batter, not a dough.  (And likely a pancake or crepe, not a flatbread)

@Ecnerwal I have a slipat arriving on Thur. - will try your suggestions.  Thanks!

@Joe "not a dough" Noted, changed tag.  "likely a pancake or crepe"  I use it as a flatbread so added crepe to title for clarity. Thks

I've rolled back your edit which changed this from a question to a recipe – questions are on topic here, recipes aren't, and significantly changing a post once it's been answered makes the website less usable. Glad you're now happy with the result though!

@dbmag9  Acknowledged and changed to accommodate original post and the resulting recipe.  Don't questions with useful(or otherwise) answers deserve results shared with contributors and the forum community?  Maybe expanded format options in the summary section?  Will have to post that suggestion in Meta.

@Mark_NoBadCake you could always post it as an answer to the question, instead

@fyrepenguin THAT is a good idea.  I'll probably leave this the way it is, if ok w/ admin - because it is short.  That said, the platform should, imo, better facilitate/encourage the presentation and discussion of results from Q/A.  Not doing so fragments information and the sense of interdependence crucial for community.  Which is, of course, the source of all cooking related problems and those of human society since ever - which is probably what you were hinting at.  :  )

"the platform should, imo, better facilitate/encourage the presentation and discussion of results from Q/A." - I mean, generally, self-answers are encouraged around here. Adding the results/answer to the question breaks the separation of Q & A. On another StackExchange site, I ended up coming back and answering my own question over a year later.

@fyrepenguin "Adding the results/answer to the question breaks the separation of Q & A."  That's a valid point with the current platform design, yes.  I'm suggesting adding an option, called 'Results'(linked but separate forum?) where, OP, having considered provided answers and comments, incorporates some or all into whatever endeavor the question was about in the first place.  The thought behind this is how fragmented human knowledge (& society) has become due to how we increasingly have used our minds (Iain McGilchrist).  I applaud you for returning to your question a year later!

Raw flour does not need to be cooked to a very high temperature to be made safe. If it had not reached that temperature, you would not be describing it as “sticky” but as “raw dough”. As it is, it is definitely safe to eat.
The recipe you describe will not produce a bread-like consistency. The dough will not have sufficient leavening power to generate a light crumb, nor sufficient structural strength to keep it until it gels. It will be gummy no matter how long you cook it, unless you cook it until it’s entirely dried out.

"As it is, it is definitely safe to eat."  THANKS.  I've been toying with the amount of water.  The goal has been to get an edible, spreadable flatbread as quickly as possible, so as it's not unsafe to eat; success.  :  )

@Mark_NoBadCake  If you substituted eggs and milk for the water, you would have a crêpe (albeit a bit flat as you don't have quite enough baking powder). I think the additional 20 min in the oven are unnecessary to cook it. With the texture you describe, it should be very similar to a crêpe in terms of thickness and will cook with similar rapidity. The oven will crisp it fairly well. You could make something like roti/chapatti in a similar time-frame if you leave out the resting of the dough and something like flatbrød with baking alone.

@bob1  I forgot to mention the egg but will have to try it with milk.  As it is, 1 min on med. heat, I get browned underside that can be lifted w/ a spatula but the top is new play-doh consistency.  Flipping it doesn't help the inside much so...20 min in the oven.  If I get it thin enough it's crispy outside and inside is like hard wet clay to crisp, depending - which is fine for my use.  This was the laziest solution w/ the equipment I have on hand!

@Mark_NoBadCake whoops - no baking powder in crepes - I was thinking pancakes/pikelets/drop scones. All the recipes are variants on each-other, so pretty similar generally. Medium heat 2-3 min per side for crepes works well for me.

@bob1 milk isn't necessary for pancakes, they can be made with any liquid, including water. But they will probably need more egg to hold together, especially when there are bulk pieces like shredded kale added. Ruhlman's ratio for pancakes is 2 parts Liquid : 1 part Egg : 1/2 part Fat : 2 parts Flour, or 2 liquid : 1 egg : 2 flour, plus fold-ins, for fritters.

@bob1 "no baking powder", "Medium heat 2-3 min per side for crepes", will try.  Thanks!  The deal with the oven is I can toss them in and return 20 min later.  Done-  Wham-bam, but your suggestion would take less time overall so...tradeoff...

[Adjusted recipe, based on comments]
Speedy's Flatbread
A tasty, expedient, versatile, nutritious pastry that can be torn & dipped, topped, used as pizza crust(from skillet, sauce and top) or as a Lembas replacement for a destined hike cross-country.
1 cup whole wheat Flour
1 egg
1/2 cup shredded Kale
1/2 tsp salt
1 tsp olive oil
~1 1/2 cups filtered water to near water consistency
Optional: 1 Tbs ground flax seed
Optional: 1/2 cup sweet corn (no topping necessary w/ this!), drained black beans, [any ingredient w/ some structural integrity(NOT peas)]
Removed:1/2 tsp baking powder(reacts to Kale, so keep separate until mixed)

Mix non-bulky ingredients with spoon; adjust consistency; use egg beater to eliminate lumps; mix in bulky ingredients
With skillet at medium heat, pour in a spiral outward within ~2.5 in. of edge. Move skillet in horizontal, circular motion(gently!) to evenly distribute batter. Remove when solid - after about 1 min.
Load cooling rack until all batter is used.
Toss in oven at 425 **F** for 15 minutes. 


